# PN532 NFC unable to SELECT FILE from Android with HCE

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, ndef

Some background: I am using an Arduino Uno with a PN532 shield to send commands to an Android phone running an HCE app.

I have tried two ways to send an APDU to do a `SELECT FILE` operation with the following APDU data. I am using the I2C interface because I suspect that the shield I'm trying to use doesn't support SPI.

The `SELECT FILE` command below does indeed work with a different shield using the SPI interface, but I can't for the life of me get it to work using I2C with my other shield.

```
uint8_t apdu[] = {
  0x00, /* CLA */
  0xA4, /* INS SELECT FILE command */
  0x04, /* P1 - select by DF name */
  0x00, /* P2  Get the first record*/
  0x07, /* Length of AID  */
  0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, /* AID  */
  0x00  /* Le  */
};
```

1. Method 1

Send NDEF formatted commands:

A) inListPassiveTarget

This works and I see the Android's UID/ncfid

B) inDataExchange with data as above APDU buffer.

This returns an error frame:

> 00 00 ff 01 ff 7f 81 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0

2. method 2

A) inListPassiveTarget

This works. Logical number 1 gets assigned to the detected passive RFID tag (i.e. my Android phone).

B) inSelect command

This works. I send the expected NDEF formatted bytes:

> 0xD4 0x54 0x01

And get back:

> 0xD5 0x55 0x00

C) Send above SELECT FILE command using the `inCommunicateThru` command.

This doesn't work. I receive a response indicating a timeout.

> 00 00 ff 03 fd d5 43 01 e7 00

So to sum up, trying inDataExchange, gives an application error failure and trying the inSelect + inCommunicateThru gives a timeout.

I have tried increasing the timeout values using an RF command, but that doesn't help.

Any help in debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

***** PROBLEM RESOLVED ******

The error frame I was getting when using inDataExchange mysteriously went away when I tried my code with a newer Samsung phone model, the Samsung Galaxy S8.  So, it was either the version of Android OS on the new S8 or perhaps a difference in firmware/hardware between the old phone and the new one that accounted for the earlier errors.